# Array.map() creates a new line for every element it creates

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a demonstration of the concept of polyrhythms as a proof-of-concept project for my React learning. I have the following as a function right now:

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(""); // I will extrapolate out to n switches
  const beatArr = [];                       // when I have the rest of the functionality
  for (var i = 1; i <= value; i++) {        // implemented.
    beatArr.push(i);
  }
  const beats = beatArr.map((x) => <Beat key={x} identifier={x} />);
```

I have two components thus far; a `<Switch />` (used to pull information from the DOM) and a `<Beat />` (takes the switches' `value` and renders that many beats).

My issue as it stands right now is that using `beatArr.map(...)` creates a new line after every `<Beat />` element, and I want it to not do that. For example with a value of 4 and three groupings of elements, right now it renders as:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

While I want it to render as:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

How can I refactor this into something that could make it work? Is this an issue with the .map() method? I have used CSS to add line breaks in between the groups, but the result as of now is:

```
1
2
3
4
1
...
```

Thanks in advance, you guys are great.

EDIT: Forked at current point for future-proofing this question; here is [current source](https://codesandbox.io/s/polyrhythm-demonstration-forked-gq3vx).

Comment: Please attach Beat component.

Comment: Added the full source, just in case. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is change you  element to  element in Beat component

```
import React from "react";

function Beat({ identifier }) {
  return <span className="beat-elem">{identifier}</span>;
}

export default Beat;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/polyrhythm-demonstration-forked-bpgdp?file=/src/Beat.js

Comment: I was hesitant to do this because it destroys the circular formatting that I had in place. `<span>` doesn't take flex-basis or width/height stipulations, and padding is finicky with responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

In your `<Beat>` component, if you use a `<span>` instead of `<div>`, it should work.

```
function Beat({ identifier }) {
return <span className="beat-elem">{identifier}</span>;
}
```